Analog of chord-and-tangent for elliptic curves in 3 or higher dimensions
For an elliptic curve defined by a Weierstrass equation (or any degree-3 polynomial equation) in $\mathbb{P}^2$, the group law has a geometric interpretation by the chord-and-tangent method.
Suppose we have an elliptic curve in say $\mathbb{P}^3$ defined as the intersection of two (e.g. degree-two) surfaces. What is the analog of the chord-and-tangent in this case?

See this pdf.

In Explicit equations in the plane for elliptic curves given
as space quartics, Qiaochu Yuan [QY2007] presents explicitly how Edwards' validation of Abel’s approach to the group law by using the Edwards curve with formulas analogous to the addition formulas for the sine and cosine:
$$(p, q) ⊕ (r, s) = 
(\frac1{a}\cdot\frac{ps + qr}{1 + pqrs},\frac1{a}\cdot \frac{qs − pr}{1 − pqrs})$$ extends to space quartics.
The below is from [QY2007]
Theorem 3.7. Every space quartic is isomorphic to a curve of the form
$$\begin{align}XY − ZW &= 0\\
X^2 + Y^2 − a^2Z^2 − a^2W^2 &= 0\end{align}\quad\quad (10)$$
Theorem 3.8. Every space quartic is birationally equivalent to a planar elliptic curve in Edwards form $$R^2T^2 + S^2T^2 = a^2T^4 + a^2R^2S^2$$
Or in affines
$$xy = z, x^2 + y^2 = a^2 + a^2z^2$$
and
$$x^2 + y^2 = a^2 + a^2x^2y^2$$
Theorem 5.1. Given a space quartic $C$ defined as in Equation (10) and two points $P'(p, q), Q'(r, s)$ on the corresponding Edwards plane curve (in affine coordinates) $C': x^2 + y^2 = a^2 + a^2x^2y^2,$ the points $O(0, a, 0), P(p, q, pq), Q(r, s, rs), (u, −v, −uv)$ are coplanar, where $(u, v) = P' + Q'$ and $O(0, a, 0)$ is the pre-image of the identity $O'$ on $C'$ and therefore the identity on $C$.
See the above (archived) linked pdf of [QY2007] for a proof.
